# How to get prototype of a registered webcomponent without instantiating it

Tags: web-component

Consider the following code in a javascript library;

```
document.registerElement('my-component', { prototype: { foo: true }});
```

It seems registerElement returns a function which can be used as a constructor.

How can I get a reference to this function later ?

```
var tempDom = document.createElement('my-component')
console.log(tempDom.__proto__)
```

Seems working but it requires creating an instance first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to save the return from registerElement() in a variable, and then use that variable later. If you do not save the return then I believe it is lost.

```
// Save the return in a variable
var mycomp = document.registerElement('my-component');

// Use the var to create the element
document.body.appendChild(new mycomp());

// Then you can do things with the new tag
var mytag = document.getElementsByTagName("my-component")[0];
mytag.textContent = "I am a my-component element.";
```

Answer (score 0):

[`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) method will give you an expected result.

```
var mc = document.registerElement(
  'my-component', { prototype: { foo: true }}
);
console.log(mc.prototype);
//⇒ my-component {foo: true}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but how later ? Element registration is done in a separate js library so I don't have chance to use mc.

Comment: An anonymous function is defined somewhere in 3rd party library and you wonder whether you can get an access to it? Would you concretize what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: document.registerElement function registers the element and stores the returned function in somewhere. I want to learn how to get a reference to the returned function.